# como filtrar ids seleccionados y visualizarlo en la url

Tags: python, djangorestframework

Hola tengo la siguiente incógnita: como puedo formular un filtro en django rest framework para listar varias id, visualizar las q selecciones y luego editarlas, la url se vería algo así como esto http://localhost:8000/caractproducto/caract/1,5,7/ donde [1,5,7] serian las id, gracias.

view

class Caracteristica(APIView):

```
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

def get(self, request):        
    queryset = CaracteristicaModel.objects.all()
    serializer = CaracteristicaSerializer(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny, ])
def Caracteristica_view(request, id):

```
try:
    caracteristica = CaracteristicaModel.objects.get(id=id)
except CaracteristicaModel.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == "GET":
    serializer = CaracteristicaSerializer(caracteristica)
    return Response(serializer.data)


elif request.method == "PUT":
    serializer = CaracteristicaSerializer(caracteristica, data=request.data)
    data = {}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        data["success"] = "update successfull"
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

ya obtuve la respuesta, recibía string en vez de array así q se deben convertir los parámetros de string en el arreglo en lo siguiente:

class FiltroListView(generics.ListAPIView):

```
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

#  queryset = CaracteristicaModel.objects.all()
   # serializer_class = CaracteristicaSerializer

```
def get(self, request, id):
    print(id)
    auxi_espec = id
    auxi_espec_lst = [int(x.strip()) for x in auxi_espec.split(',') if x]
    queryset = CaracteristicaModel.objects.filter(id__in=auxi_espec_lst)
    serializer = CaracteristicaSerializer(queryset, many=True) 

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

y asi obtuve la url:
path('filtro//', FiltroListView.as_view())

y me entrega las id en postman http://localhost:8000/caractproducto/filtro/2,4,5/